# SAS: Suppress 'Sum' for one of series of variables in PROC MEANS

Tags: sas

I'm running the following PROC MEANS command, but would like to suppress the value of SUM for the variable margin, as the sum of this percentage has no meaningful value.

```
proc means data=have N sum mean median maxdec=2 order=freq STACKODS;
var turnover margin;
run;
```

Is there any way to specify the statistics to be output according to each variable? I'm output much more than the sample code above and am creating Latex markup code automatically from the output, so it would be very helpful if the SUM for the variable margin was missing.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Given you're not going through a dataset if I remember the rest of your program, I don't know of any way you could do that.  You might have to output to a dataset and then postprocess it, then proc print/report/whatever out to your final latex destination.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use proc means?

I believe you can achieve your desired outcome using Proc Tabulate.  Check out the attached:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/264-2008.pdf

Comment: Hi - please expand on that link in your answer.  The Stack Overflow community considers "link-only" answers (a link without at least sufficient explanation in-answer to be useful without the link) to be inferior, because the link might break over time, and additionally the user should not be expected to have to click the link to understand the solution.

Comment: Joe - Tabulate is a complex procedure with many options and potential outcomes.  The original poster has not provided any data, nor required outcome from an output structure perspective, so the least they can do is read an the article to see if it meets their requirements.  They have specified Proc Means as the procedure they are interested in, so I am not wasting my time if this is their exam question where they must use MEANS or state why it can not be used.  I'm sorry it is so hard to expect a user to click a link and obtain the answer themselves.

Comment: I fully understand PROC TABULATE.  However, this answer as it stands does not meet the standards for a "good answer", as I noted earlier.  It is not primarily about the user clicking a link; it is about the purpose of Stack Overflow (being a database of questions and answers, not being a database of questions and links which often die).  If you cannot (or do not want to) explain in the body of the answer enough to make it stand on its own, it is better not to post the answer, and instead mention it as a comment or something like that.